# can we change the basic extraction behavior of a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

dictionary extraction normal method

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
print(d['a'])  # prints: 1
```

requirement:

```
print(d['a', 'b'])  # should print: [1, 2]
```

will this be possible by subclassing `dict` and modifying `__getitem__()` method, if possible, how?

Comment: could also always just write this requirement as a function instead of messing with a perfectly normal datatype. something like `fetch(dict, key_list)`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried this yet, did you get stuck anywhere?

Comment: I would advice against subclassing built-ins and altering their behavior, will be very confusing for others when you're using invented syntax with seemingly ordinary dictionaries. Would be best to just make a function like @ParitoshSingh suggested.

Comment: @ruohola: subclassing is *fine*, as long as you don't replace all `dict` objects. Loads of good Python projects subclass `dict`, including the standard library (`collections.defaultdict` and `collections.Counter` both are such subclasses). Python is not Ruby, luckily.

Comment: @MartijnPieters very true, this just screams that OP wants to be able to do this with any random dictionary...

Comment: `operator.itemgetter` implements something like this.

Comment: @ruohola: creating a new instance from an existing dictionary is not a problem either though, e.g. `d = MultiKeyDict(d)`.

Comment: @hpaulj: that inverts the operation, though. `itemgetter('a', 'b')(d)` is not all that readable, in this specific scenario. Then just stick with `[d[k] for k in ('a', 'b')]`..

Comment: @MartijnPieters  i have no idea how  dict.__getitem__() method looks like, how can i see its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use subclassing, this will do the job quite nicely:

```
class CustomDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.dic = dic

    def __getitem__(self, items):
        values = []
        for item in items:
            values.append(self.dic[item])
        return values if len(values) > 1 else values[0]


d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

new_d = CustomDict(d)

print(new_d['a'])
print(new_d['a', 'b'])
print(new_d['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(new_d['a', 'c', 'd'])
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 1
> [1, 2]
> [1, 2, 3]
> [1, 3, 4]
> ```

Explanation:

The `new_d` is an object of the `CustomDict` class, it will always fall back to the parent class's methods (so that looping over the object and other things you might want to do to a dictionary work) except when one of the overriden methods (init, getitem) get called.

So when one uses `new_d['a', 'b']` the overriden `__getitem__` method gets called. The overriden method uses the `__getitem__` of the `self.dic` (which is a normal dictionary) to actually access the dictionary values for every key given.

Answer (score -2):

```
def ret_multiple(dict, *args)
    for k in args:
        if k in dict:
            ret.append(dict[k])
    return ret

vals = ret_multiple(d, 'a', 'b')
```

Comment: Why use a mutable default value for `keys` at all? At the very least make it a `()` tuple so it can't be accidentally modified. And you could just use a `*keys` catch-all argument and so support `ret_multiple(d, 'a', 'b')`.

Comment: Idk dude I just wrote this super fast. And I'm not that smart

Comment: @amchugh89 you could initialize `ret` however, not use the built-in `dict` and add `:` on the function definition line. Maybe superfast was *way too fast*.

Comment: Even though this may answer the question, there is no explanation of your code. Please update your answer to provide an explanation of what you are doing. Thanks!